# log4net: different info colors for different types

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net

I have log4net and I want to have different info colors for different types (for two special types) in the same assembly. Is it possible? If it possible what should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Update: Appender is supposed to be ColoredConsoleAppender.

Comment: It's possible when logging to the Console.  This is your intent, yes?

Comment: Yes, definitely ColoredConsoleAppender.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="Common" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">  
            <loggerToMatch value="Custom1" />  
            <acceptOnMatch value="false" />  
        </filter>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">  
            <loggerToMatch value="Custom2" />  
            <acceptOnMatch value="false" />  
        </filter>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="Custom1" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
        <mapping>
            <level value="INFO" />
            <backColor value="Blue" />
        </mapping>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="Custom2" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
        <mapping>
            <level value="INFO" />
            <backColor value="Light Blue" />
        </mapping>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="Common"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="Namespace.Foo">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="Custom1" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="Namespace.Bar">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="Custom2" />
    </logger>
</log4net>
```

Here I have made two appenders where the give different colours to `DEBUG` level.
At the bottom I have made `ColoredConsoleAppenderOne` only be active for type `Com.Foo` and `ColoredConsoleAppenderTwo` only be active for type `Com.Bar`

Comment: Ok, thank you, it works. But If I've already defined CCA in a root then I have duplicate number of messages. Is it possible to fix?

Comment: Updated the config sample, this should work (have not tested it).

Comment: Great! Works!!! Thank you very much! Small correction -- loggerToMatch  should be logger name, not appender name.